# Bootstrap breaks multiple children drowdown by main dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I have done a bit of Jquery to change multiple children drowdown by main dropdown.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7ffI.png)

The issue I am having is as soon as I add the bootstrap styles "form-control select picker" it breaks as it converts the code to be in a different format.

The code for the Jquery to change multiple children drowdown by main dropdown is below. I would also like to add a save to save the relevant children when the relevant main dropdown has been selected:

```
<select class="search_top_options">
    <option class="saleButton">property sales</option>
    <option class="rentalButton">long lets</option>
</select>

$('.saleButton').click(function () {
      $('.rentalSearch').hide();
      $('.saleButton').removeClass("search_top_tab").addClass("search_top_tab_selected");
      $('.rentalButton').removeClass("search_top_tab_selected").addClass("search_top_tab");
      $('.saleSearch').fadeIn('fast');
  });
  $('.rentalButton').click(function () {
      $('.saleSearch').hide();
      $('.rentalButton').removeClass("search_top_tab").addClass("search_top_tab_selected");
      $('.saleButton').removeClass("search_top_tab_selected").addClass("search_top_tab");
      $('.rentalSearch').fadeIn('fast');
  });
```

How can I do this? Code which is getting formatted by bootstrap sin below screenshot (won't let me attach it onto this ticket):

[image here of broken bootstrap select code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyaLH.png)

Comment: HI @IamRaviteja, I have now added the html

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is, that the "click" event you are listening won't work on options.

In your case you can try to get the value of your select. The code provided is a little change to yours, but should give you a hint on how to solve your problem.

```
<select class="search_top_options">
  <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option class="saleButton">property sales</option>
  <option class="rentalButton">long lets</option>
</select>

<div class="saleSearch">
saleSearch content
</div>

<div class="rentalSearch">
rentalSearch content
</div>

$('.search_top_options').on('change', function() {
    $(this).find('option:not(selected)').hide();
  if ($(this).val() == 'property sales') {
    $('.rentalSearch').hide();
    $('.saleSearch').fadeIn();
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'long lets') {
    $('.saleSearch').hide();
    $('.rentalSearch').fadeIn();
  }
});

.rentalSearch {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tw0g5jeh/

Comment: Thanks, but the code works fine as it is, the problem is when bootstrap ids are applied, it converts the code and stops it from working (code it makes is in the description under "image here of broken bootstrap select code")

Comment: Anybody out there that can help?